# What does myFunction(x:y:xs) mean in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I came across one thing that I can seem to come around.So I have this function:

```
merge :: [Int] -> [Int]
merge xs = merged ++ padding

where padding          = replicate (length xs - length merged) 0
      merged           = combine (filter (/= 0) xs)
      combine (x:y:xs) | x == y    = x * 2 : combine xs
                       | otherwise = x     : combine (y:xs) 
      combine x        = x
```

The problem is that I can't quite grasp what combine does.I did my research and found that

```
myFunction(x:xs) ...
```

represents that "x" is somehow the head of my list,and I can do stuff with it,right?Does that mean that in `myFunction(x:y:xs) ...`
"x" is the last element and "y" would be the second to the last element in xs?Is this right or am I terribly wrong?Also what about the ":" after "| x == y    = x * 2",I learned that in Haskell ":" means appending a value to a list,but in this context I really can't quite understand what it does...Some help would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x:y:xs` is a pattern that says, "This is a list with at least 2 elements.We will call the first and second elements of this list x and y. The remaining sublist, which we will call xs may be empty or non-empty". That is, it represents both the list [1,2] and [1,2,3,4.....] but not [1].

Your second query can be answered by rewriting

`| x == y    = x * 2 : combine xs`

as

`| (x == y)  = ((x * 2) : combine xs)` for clarity. This is a standard if-else flow, except that Haskell does not require you to put those parentheses explicitly. Note that the 'pipes' are called guards and work similar to a switch-case statement in Java/C#.

Comment: So if I would have something like "combine [2,2,4,8]",the result of this would be [4,4,8],am I geting this right?

Comment: Yep, exactly that!

Comment: Yey,thanks allot for your answer,this really helped me,Haskell is mercilessly,at least in the begining

Comment: No problem. In case you haven't already stumbled upon it, you can use Learn You A Haskell to start off nice and easy. http://learnyouahaskell.com/